# AngularJS: Can't get access value of isolate scope property in directive

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-router

#### Problem:

In a directive nested within 3 ui-views, I can't access the values of my isolate scope. `scope.values` returns `{}` but when I console.log `scope` I can see all the values on the `values` property.

In a different app I can make this works and I converted this one to that method as well but it still doesn't work and I'm tracing the routes, ctrl's and I can't find the difference between the two.

**Where I'm trying to access it from**

Init App > ui-view > ui-view > ui-view > form-elements > form-accordion-on

#### What I'm working with:

The view

```
<ul class='form-elements'>
    <li
        class='row-fluid'
        ng-hide='group.hidden'
        ng-repeat='group in main.card.groups'
        card='main.card'
        form-element
        values='values'
        group='group'>
    </li>
</ul>
```

This directive contains tons of different form types and calls their respective directives.

```
.directive('formElement', [function () {
    return {
        scope: {
            values: '=',
            group: '='
        },
        link: function(scope, element) {
            l(scope.$parent.values);
            element.attr('data-type', scope.group.type);
        },
        restrict: 'AE',
        template: "<label ng-hide='group.type == \"section-break\"'>" +
            "{{ group.name }}" +
            "<strong ng-if='group.required' style='font-size: 20px;' class='text-error'>*</strong> " +
            "<i ng-if='group.hidden' class='icon-eye-close'></i>" +
        "</label>" +
        "<div ng-switch='group.type'>" +
            "<div ng-switch-when='accordion-start' form-accordion-on card='card' values='values' group='group'></div>" +
            "<div ng-switch-when='accordion-end' form-accordion-off values='values' class='text-center' group='group'><hr class='mbs mtn'></div>" +
            "<div ng-switch-when='address' form-address values='values' group='group'>" +
        "</div>"
    };
}])
```

This is the directive an example directive.

```
.directive('formAccordionOn', ['$timeout', function($timeout) {
    return {
        scope: {
            group: '=',
            values: '='
        },
        template: "<div class='btn-group'>" +
            "<button type='button' class='btn' ng-class='{ active: values[group.trackers[0].id] == option }' ng-model='values[group.trackers[0].id]' ng-click='values[group.trackers[0].id] = option; toggleInBetweenElements()' ng-repeat='option in group.trackers[0].dropdown track by $index'>{{ option }}</button>" +
        "</div>",
        link: function(scope, element) {
            console.log(scope) // returns the scope with the values property and it's values.
            console.log(scope.values); // returns {}
        })

        // etc code ...
```

Closely related to but I'm using `=` on every isolate scope object:
[AngularJS: Can't get a value of variable from ctrl scope into directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17978702/angularjs-cant-get-a-value-of-variable-from-ctrl-scope-into-directive)

**Update**

Sorry if this is a bit vague I've been at this for hours trying to figure out a better solution.   This is just what I have atm.

**Update 2**

I cannot believe it was that `simple`.

```
var init = false;
scope.$watch('values', function(newVal, oldVal) {
    if (_.size(newVal) !== _.size(oldVal)) {
        // scope.values has the value I sent with it!
        init = true;
        getInitValues();
    }
});
```

But this feels hacky, is there a more elegant way of handling this?

**Update 3**

I attach a flag in my ctrl when the values are ready and when that happens bam!

```
scope.$watch('values', function(newVal) {
    if (newVal.init) {
        getInitValues();
    }
});
```

Comment: Is there anywhere online we can see your setup?  Your situation sounds very strange, and is hard to answer with just the code you've given.

Comment: @Hylianpuffball I have a huge codebase area there any snippets you think might be helpful? Routes, views, etc.?

Comment: you could also use `$observe` instead of `$watch` to observe the changes on the directive attributes (scope data binding), but it's still *hacky*. It would be nice if angular provided an `init` event for directives, as the `$destroy` event exists for unloading them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output of `console.log()` is a live view (that may depend on the browser though).

When you examine the output of `console.log(scope);` `scope` has already been updated in the meantime. What you see are the **current** values. That is when the `link` function is executed `scope.values` is indeed an empty object. Which in turn means that `values` get updated after the execution of `link`, obviously.

If your actual problem is not accessing `values` during the **execution** of `link`, the you need to provide more details.

### Update

According to your comments and edits you seem to need some one time initialization, as soon as the values are there. I suggest the following:

```
var init = scope.$watch('values', function(newVal, oldVal) {
  if (newVal ==== oldVal) { //Use this if values is replaced, otherwise use a comparison of your choice
    getInitValues();
    init();
  }
});
```

`init()` removes the watcher.

Comment: Interesting... but yes I am trying to access values during execution of `link` or `controller`.

Comment: But `values` seems to be empty at that point. So you can't. Maybe you can achieve what you want with `scope.$watch('values', function(... `

Comment: Good idea I'm setting up tests for this right now (I'm converting to TDD) I'll add that in.

Comment: It worked! Is there a more elegant way of handling this?  Should I be declaring all this in the controller phase of the directive?  Am I just following a bad pattern?

Comment: @MichaelCalkins I updated my answer. Usually `$watch` is the way to go if the directive needs to react to changes in the model.